# add cpp classes into android project

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opus, speex

How can I add a .cpp class (like speex or opus) into my android studio project ?
I already tried to insert using externalNativeBuild like :

```
externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=Application.mk"
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            cFlags "-I\$(LOCAL_PATH)/jnispeex.cpp -I\$(LOCAL_PATH)/jnicelt11.cpp -I\$(LOCAL_PATH)/jnicelt7.cpp -I\$(LOCAL_PATH)/jniopus -D__EMX__ -DUSE_KISS_FFT -DFIXED_POINT -DEXPORT='' -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fvisibility=hidden -DOPUS_BUILD -DVAR_ARRAYS -Wno-traditional -DFIXED_POINT"
        }
    }
```

but it does't work.
I will be so appreciated if anyone helps

Comment: The `-I` compiler option is to specify paths, not source files.

Comment: so how should i address that the source files?

Comment: In your `Android.mk` file(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `CMakelists.txt` for your Android NDK build and configure your CPP files inside the `Cmakelists.txt`. Some related links for your reference:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182431/8034839
2. [Where to place JNI/native libraries in Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046767/where-to-place-jni-native-libraries-in-android-studio-project/52048933#52048933)